# Neural network with two inputs of different sizes and colour depth (RGB and grayscale)

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am trying to figure out how to build a neural network with two inputs of different sizes.

- one 3D, grayscale volume
- one 2D, color picture

This is what I think it should look like in tf :

```
# Shape of 3D input [height, width, depth, channels]
input_1 = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [height, width, depth, 1])
# Shape of 2D input [height, width, channels]
input_2 = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [height, width, 3])
```

These placeholders can't be merged together to serve as input to the network, because their shapes are different.

The only way I see to merge these 2 inputs into 1 is to append the grayscale slices of the volume to the 3 channels of the colour picture. However, I doubt this would lead to good results when actually training the network: I would like to have 2 loss functions, one for each input.

```
# Shape of 3D input [height, width, depth, channels]
input_1 = [ tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [height, width, 1]) for i in range(0, depth) ]
# Shape of 2D input [height, width, channels]
input_1.append([tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [height, width, 1]) for i in range(0,3)])
input_1 = tf.stack(input_1, axis=-1)
```

How should I structure my input to solve this problem?

Comment: You don't need to merge the placeholders. In the `Session`'s `feed_dict=` argument, give two different images with the two placeholders as keys.

Comment: I did some testing, even if I can put 2 inputs into feed_dict, I still have a problem for the input of tf.nn.conv2d. Here is one of my layers :

`conv1 = tf.contrib.layers.batch_norm(tf.nn.conv2d(placeholder, ...))`

How can I construct a single placeholder object, or input, from the 2 I have ?

Comment: You can do a number of things, but typically in these kinds of problems where you have multimodal data you have two networks that are later merged into one. So you can have Conv2D for the image, Conv3D for the volume (one or more layers, as you prefer), then flatten the output, maybe have some dense layers, and merge the output of each "subnetwork" into a single vector. This would again probably go through dense layers to reach the final output.

Comment: If that's the case, I insist you to use Keras API.

Comment: How would Keras help me here ? I found [this](https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2019/02/04/keras-multiple-inputs-and-mixed-data/) resource that implements multiple inputs with Keras in the same way jdehesa described : 2 subnetworks that are merged into one.

@jdehesa Thank you for the advice, I will try it. I was hoping to just throw everything into the network and let it sort it all out, but it looks like that's not possible

Comment: @JMuller I mean you _can_ throw everything into a network, flatten inputs into vectors, concatenate them and put some dense layers. The problem is it's probably going to be way less effective than using conv layers, and for that you need to keep the 2D and 3D structures of the inputs. You can think of more strategies, like train a network with the 2D data only, another with the 3D data only, then combine the trained networks (e.g. removing the last layer of each and merging, "averaging" the output of each one, ...). Haven't done anything similar but I've seen things like that in papers.